# Material-ui response to breaking change in React 15.4.0? "Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/EventPluginHub'"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

React v 15.4.0 was released this morning and seems to have included a change that broke react-tap-event-plugin v1.0.0 producing this error:

```
$ npm build
> myProject@0.1.47 build /.../myProject
> node scripts/build.js
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to create a production build. Reason:
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/EventPluginHub' in /.../myProject/node_modules/react-tap-event-plugin/src
```

(note: I cleaned up the output a little)

According to [THIS react-tap-event issue log](https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin/issues/85) version 2.0.0 of react-tap-event fixes the build problem.  However, material-ui is still using react-tap-event version 1.0.0.  What are the options here?  The only options I can think of are:

- Downgrade react and other packages as described in the link above
- Wait for Material-UI to upgrade to react-tap-event 2.0.0

Any other solutions here?  I'm pretty much dead in the water if I wanted to use react 15.4.0, as far as I can tell.

Comment: material-ui issue: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/5573

Answer (score 11):

Almost make sure you update the `react-tap-event-plugin` to the right version of react.

Comment: to be specific update material-ui to `^0.16.0` and react-tap-event-plugin to `^2.0.0` in your package.json if using react `^15.4.0`

Answer (score 7):

material-ui version 0.16.3 is released to address the problem.

Comment: I upgraded `material-ui` to 0.16.3 and still same error :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by going through next steps:

```
- delete `"react": "{your-version}"` line from package.json;
- delete node_modules dir; 
- run `npm i`;
- run `npm i react --save`.
```

Answer (score 0):

in React 16.4 removes a lot of internals (#121) this plugin depends on and will break the plugin.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tap-event-plugin

as solution with new release of React uninstall thia plugin and deleted any imports and uses from source [Reaction Commerce: TypeError: require(...).__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009195/reaction-commerce-typeerror-require-secret-internals-do-not-use-or-you)
and
[Is react-tap-event-plugin still needed in 2018?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939045/is-react-tap-event-plugin-still-needed-in-2018)
i removed react-tap-event-plugin from my reactjs project. it work for me

Comment: Please edit your answer to be a little more clear...