# Reaction Commerce: TypeError: require(...).__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Upgrading Reaction Commerce from 1.4.x to 1.5.x with `rc run` I'm getting this error in Firefox:

```
TypeError: require(...).__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED is undefined
```

and these errors in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'EventPluginHub' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'marketplaceEnabled' of undefined
```

I found [imports/plugins/core/ui/client/helpers/react-template-helper.js](https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction/blob/master/imports/plugins/core/ui/client/helpers/react-template-helper.js#L2) where React is mainly being loaded I think. Any ideas what could be missing here?

Issue Source Code:
https://github.com/MassDistributionMedia/rc-ca-blinds/tree/custom-cart_rc1.5.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove react-tap-event-plugin from client/modules/core/main.js. It's no longer necessary.