# Is react-tap-event-plugin still needed in 2018?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

Is https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin still needed nowadays? Or it has been implemented into React's source directly and tap delay is gone.

Comment: The first paragraph of https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin explains it, doesn't it? These are browsers and not React that address the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the answer inside your own link.

[Developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away)

To remove the 300-350ms tap delay, all you need is the following in the  of your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

The usage of the plugin is deprecated because new versions of React removes a lot of internals  this plugin depends on.

Since the problem has been fixed in most browsers by now you should migrate away from this plugin.